# Why can't bind my domain name and vps_ip?

Tags: dns, domain, vps

1.The apache server was installed on my vps_ip.
[image]

2.My domain name was bind with my vps_ip in namesilo management web page.

[image]

3.Why the namesilo welcome web page displayed when to input `www.hgoods.site` in firefox ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ host www.hgoods.site
www.hgoods.site is an alias for parking.namesilo.com.
parking.namesilo.com has address 45.35.25.197
parking.namesilo.com has address 45.35.195.10
parking.namesilo.com has address 167.114.213.199
parking.namesilo.com has address 45.35.73.201
parking.namesilo.com has address 164.132.212.72
parking.namesilo.com has address 45.63.67.173
parking.namesilo.com has address 107.161.23.204
parking.namesilo.com has address 45.32.85.62
parking.namesilo.com has address 104.238.136.38
```

The domain has a CNAME entry. delete it. the cname maps your domain to parking.namesilo.com.

Comment: note any change will take one hour, your current ttl is set to 1hour